# Wordpress api v2 filter posts by tag

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

How can I use wordpress api v2 to get all posts by a specific tag?

For example, I have the tag 'programming' with the id '24'.

How can I fetch all posts containing this id?

I've tried

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[tag]=24
```

which is mentioned here: https://1fix.io/blog/2015/07/20/query-vars-wp-api/

but that does not work.

Comment: try simply /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=24  for futher notice if you want post WITH ALL (multiple) tags  use + : tags=24+22+34   if you want posts WTH ANY OF use comma : tags=24,22,34

Comment: Thanks, I've missed the 's'!

Comment: How can i filter by year and month?