# Wordpress REST API: How to retrieve posts tagged by multiple tags?

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

Some people [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871851/wordpress-api-v2-filter-posts-by-tag#comment76725534_44871851) using `/posts?tags=tag_id_1,tag_id_2` or `/posts?tags[]=tag_id_1&tags[]=tag_id_2`
but wordpress seems to be returning posts that are tagged either with tag1 OR tag2. What I actually need is posts tagged with tag1 AND tag2.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I will share with you what I have done.

I created a new endpoint for my custom needs,
which ends like `myapi/v1/posts/tag1/tag2`

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myapi/v1', 'posts/(?P<tag_1>[-\w]+)/(?P<tag_2>[-\w]+)',array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_posts_set'
  ));
});
```

Then, created

```
function get_posts_set($request) {

    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $request['category_name'],
        'tag_slug__and'    => array( $request['tag_1'],$request['tag_2'] ),
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    if (empty($posts)) {
        return new WP_Error( 'empty_category', 'there is no post in this category', array('status' => 404) );
    }


    // Following code is my processing of output. Customize it to suit your needs

    $post_data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $posts as $post) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $post_title = remove_html_comments($post->post_title);
        $post_content = remove_html_comments($post->post_content);
        $post_data[ $i ][ 'id' ] = $post_id;
        $post_data[ $i ][ 'title' ] = $post_title;
        $post_data[ $i ][ 'content' ] = $post_content;
        $i++;
    }

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($post_data);
    $response->set_status(200);

    return $response;
}

function remove_html_comments($content = '') {
    return preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
}
```

This will return only the PostID, Post Title and Post Content with HTML formatting for direcr reuse. Hope this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily, it turns out:

`/posts?tags[operator]=AND&tags[terms]=tag_id_1,tag_id_2`

Answer (score 0):

I find this code snippet in `class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php`,
but confused, don't know how to bring them into this by url parameters.

```
if ( rest_is_array( $tax_include ) ) {
    $terms = $tax_include;
} elseif ( rest_is_object( $tax_include ) ) {
    $terms            = empty( $tax_include['terms'] ) ? array() : $tax_include['terms'];
    $include_children = ! empty( $tax_include['include_children'] );

    if ( isset( $tax_include['operator'] ) && 'AND' === $tax_include['operator'] ) {
        $operator = 'AND';
    }
}
```

And, God! Michał Tatarynowicz enlightened me! The answer is absolute true!

The usage is just like: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags[operator]=AND&tags[terms]=13,15`